# collect subprocess outputs and write to excel in python

Tags: python, excel, text

I wrote a loop in python to cope with a list of tasks, and during every loop certain outputs (plain text) from either stderr or stdout will be generated, what I want is trying to collect them inside python and at the end write them together into excel. I also tried before write them respectively after every loop into excel (through pandas) but it takes too long to run through all tasks as I suppose every export has to overwrite what already in excel. I would like to ask if there is suitable packages to cope with text in python in this regards.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you call subprocess run capture_output=True to the arguments like this:

```
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], capture_output=True)
```

Second, depending on your data, you'll need to 'parse' the output using str split or NumPy.

And for the excel part, try using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-excel-spreadsheets-in-python/#:%7E:text=Getting%20Started,come%20in%2Dbuilt%20with%20Python.) guide.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for  the reply. May I ask what is difference between stdout=PIPE and capture_output?

Comment: Hi,
please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#:~:text=If%20capture_output%20is,of%20capture_output. about the differences between them.

TL;DR mainly you'll use stdout=PIPE when you want to capture also the stderr output.
if you only want stdout, you should use capture_output and receive the output from the return value and not from another call to popen.communicate() which returns binary data